# Local database for windows xp application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-xp, local-database

I'm writing an application for a bunch of xp users. My application should be able to run on the minimum requirements (the least possible, the users use old old computers).

At first I started developing on VS 2012 and .Net 3.5 + SqlLocalDB. Later I found out that xp does not support SqlLocalDB, then I switched to SqlExpress and I still can not install my application on xp (even though if it worked, it was a little heavy cause you need 20 minutes to install it, not a one click solution), and it does not give a proper error message, it just says this application is not a valid win32 application.

I am even switching to VS 2010 to make things clearer in my head, can't get where the problem is.

By the way I am using LinqToSql technology so I need the DB to be Sql, even more on the other versions (.Net 4.0 and SqlLocalDB) I can use .mdf database files, so I would rather not to go around Access database.

Anyway, this is the case : I need to run an application with .Net 3.5 and a Local Database, I want the installation to be as easy as a one click setup.

I am confused. Please share your knowlege with me.

Comment: Are you sure .NET is a good choice for these computers?  (For that matter, are you sure they even have .NET installed?)  It sounds as if native code would be preferable.

Comment: Actually native is the best choice but the problem is that the project is 90% complete, any .net local db solution? :|

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) ?
Seems to be good candidate.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need .NET Framework 4.0.2 (or above) + Windows Vista SP2 (or above) to use SqlLocalDb so you can not build an application with .NET 3.5 & LocalDb for windows XP.

Try using .NET 3.5 + SQL Server Compact 4.0 sp1 instead